# Share scaling of differntly sized subplots' axes (not sharing axes)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scaling, subplot

With matplotlib, I want to plot two graphs with the same x-axis scale, but I want to show different sized sections. How can I accomplish that?

So far I can plot differently sized subplots with GridSpec or same sized ones who share the x-axis. When I try both at once, the smaller subplot has the same axis but smaller scaled, while I want the same scaling and a different axis, so sharing the axis might be a wrong idea.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
y=np.sin(x)

x2=np.linspace(0,5,60)
y2=np.cos(x2)

fig=plt.figure()

gs=GridSpec(2,3)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
ax1.plot(x,y)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,:-1])
    #using sharex=ax1 here decreases the scaling of ax2 too much
ax2.plot(x2,y2)

plt.show()
```

I want the x.axes to have the same scaling, i.e. the same x values are always exactly on top of each other, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5VJI.png) should give you an idea. The smaller plot's frame could be expanded or fit the plot, that doesn't matter. [As it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97MXR.png), the scales don't match.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with plotting questions, it's very helpful if you can provide a visual representation of what you want. I suspect you'll want to pull the axis information from ax1 using `get_` functions and then use `ax2.set_` as needed after correcting for the size difference

Comment: I added a figure of what if looks like and of what hopefully gives you an idea what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is still a bit rough. I'm sure there's a slightly more elegant way to do this, but you can create a custom `transformation` (see [Transformations Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html)) between the Axes coordinates of `ax2` and the data coordinates of `ax1`. In other word, your calculating what is the data-value (according to `ax1`) at the position corresponding to the left and right edges of `ax2`, and then adjust the `xlim` of `ax2` accordingly.

Here is a demonstration showing that it works even if the second subplot is not aligned in any particular way with the first.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

x=np.linspace(0,25,100)
y=np.sin(x)

x2=np.linspace(10,30,60)
y2=np.cos(x2)

fig=plt.figure()

gs=GridSpec(2,6)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
ax1.plot(x,y)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,3:-1])
ax2.plot(x2,y2)

# here is where the magic happens
trans = ax2.transAxes + ax1.transData.inverted()
((xmin,_),(xmax,_)) = trans.transform([[0,1],[1,1]])
ax2.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)

# for demonstration, show that the vertical lines end up aligned
for ax in [ax1,ax2]:
    for pos in [15,20]:
        ax.axvline(pos)

plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**: One possible refinement would be to do the transform in [the `xlim_changed` event callback](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#the-axes-class). That way, the axes stay in sync even when zooming/panning in the first axes.

There is also a slight issue with `tight_layout()` as you noted, but that is easily fixed by calling the callback function directly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec


def on_xlim_changed(event):
    # here is where the magic happens
    trans = ax2.transAxes + ax1.transData.inverted()
    ((xmin, _), (xmax, _)) = trans.transform([[0, 1], [1, 1]])
    ax2.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)


x = np.linspace(0, 25, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

x2 = np.linspace(10, 30, 60)
y2 = np.cos(x2)

fig = plt.figure()


gs = GridSpec(2, 6)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
ax1.plot(x, y)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 3:-1])
ax2.plot(x2, y2)

# for demonstration, show that the vertical lines end up aligned
for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    for pos in [15, 20]:
        ax.axvline(pos)

# tight_layout() messes up the axes xlim
# but can be fixed by calling on_xlim_changed()
fig.tight_layout()
on_xlim_changed(None)

ax1.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', on_xlim_changed)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed and it works perfectly no matter where the subplots are located. Two things I noticed which could help prevent any bugs (but might be very obvious) is setting grid, ticks etc. before the transformation. Also doesn't work with tight layout

Comment: I've added some refinements to keep the axes in sync when panning/zooming, as well as a fix for `tight_layout()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest setting limits of the second axis based on the limits of ax1.

Try this!

```
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,:-1])
ax2.plot(x2,y2)
lb, ub = ax1.get_xlim()
# Default margin is 0.05, which would be used for auto-scaling, hence reduce that here
# Set lower bound and upper bound based on the grid size, which you choose for second plot
ax2.set_xlim(lb, ub *(2/3) -0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]