# Sharing axes with different scales

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to share axes that does not have the same scale.

Let's say we have an image of size (128, 128), and a downscaled version of that image of shape (32, 32), so there is a ratio of 4 between them.

What I would like to do is to have the same functionality as shared axes, but when zooming on the (0, 0, 16, 16) rectangle on the first image, it will automatically zoom on the (0, 0, 4, 4) rectangle on the second image.

I have no idea how to implement that, I guess it will have something to do with transforms.

The base code I would like to work on:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Hh, Wh = 128, 128
Hl, Wl = 32, 32

gridh, gridw = np.mgrid[:Hh, :Wh]

xh = np.sin(gridh) + np.cos(gridw)
xl = np.array(Image.fromarray(xh).resize(size=(Hl, Wl)))

fig, (axh1, axl, axh2) = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

axh1.sharex(axh2)
axh1.sharey(axh2)

axh1.imshow(xh)
axh2.imshow(xh)
axl.imshow(xl)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, using callbacks, taking inspiration from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54042200/13636407).

So sharing the code I wrote here in case it helps someone.

Result as expected, after some random shared zooming:

[image: share_axes_scaled]

The functions that does the job:

```py
from functools import partial
from itertools import permutations


def share_axes_scaled_images(axes, scales):
    num_axes = len(axes)
    assert len(scales) == num_axes
    for idx_src, idx_tgt in permutations(range(num_axes), r=2):
        scale = scales[idx_tgt] / scales[idx_src]
        xlim_callback = partial(sharex_scaled, tgt_ax=axes[idx_tgt], scale=scale)
        axes[idx_src].callbacks.connect("xlim_changed", xlim_callback)
        ylim_callback = partial(sharey_scaled, tgt_ax=axes[idx_tgt], scale=scale)
        axes[idx_src].callbacks.connect("ylim_changed", ylim_callback)


def sharex_scaled(src_ax, tgt_ax, scale):
    """scale is the size of tgt_ax over the size of src_ax"""
    newlims = tuple((x + 0.5) * scale - 0.5 for x in src_ax.get_xlim())
    with tgt_ax.callbacks.blocked(signal="xlim_changed"):
        tgt_ax.set_xlim(newlims)


def sharey_scaled(src_ax, tgt_ax, scale):
    """scale is the size of tgt_ax over the size of src_ax"""
    newlims = tuple((y + 0.5) * scale - 0.5 for y in src_ax.get_ylim())
    with tgt_ax.callbacks.blocked(signal="ylim_changed"):
        tgt_ax.set_ylim(newlims)
```

The main script for reproducibility:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage.data import lily

def main():
    im = lily()[:256, :256, 0]
    num_axes = 3

    scales = [1 / s for s in range(1, num_axes + 1)]
    images = [imresize(im, scale=s) for s in scales]

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=num_axes)
    for ax, im in zip(axes, images):
        ax.imshow(im)

    share_axes_scaled_images(axes, scales)

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


def imresize(x, scale):
    size = tuple(int(s * scale) for s in x.shape)
    return np.array(Image.fromarray(x).resize(size=size))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```